# Data from MySQL - If users have the same number of points - show in one row

Tags: php, mysql

How can I make if player X has the same number of points as any other player, so that it displays them in 1 row?

table users:

```
`uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`points_first` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`points_second` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
```

My Query:

```
SELECT uid, username, points_first, points_second
FROM users
LIMIT 5
```

Results:

[image]

PHP to sort data DESC and display using templates:

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT uid, username, points_first, points_second FROM users');
        $no = $noFirst = $noSecond = 0;
        $dataFirstPoints = $dataSecondPoints = [];
        $i = 0;
        while($row = $db->fetch_array($query)){
            if($row['points_first'] != 0){
                $dataFirstPoints[$i]['points'] = $row['points_first'];
                $dataFirstPoints[$i]['username'] = $row['username'];
            }
            if($row['points_second'] != 0){
                $dataSecondPoints[$i]['points'] = $row['points_second'];
                $dataSecondPoints[$i]['username'] = $row['username'];
            }
            $i++;
            if($row['points_second'] === 0) $firstRows = "<div class=\"nodata\">No Data</div>";
            if($row['points_first'] === 0) $secondRows = "<div class=\"nodata\">No Data</div>";
        }
        arsort($dataFirstPoints);
        arsort($dataSecondPoints);
        foreach($dataFirstPoints as $data){
            $points = $data['points'];
            $noFirst++;
            $no = $noFirst;
            eval("\$secondRows .= \"".$templates->get("rows")."\";");
        }
        foreach($dataSecondPoints as $key => $data){
            $points = $data['points'];
            $noSecond++;
            $no = $noSecond;
            eval("\$firstRows .= \"".$templates->get("rows")."\";");
        }
        eval("\$main = \"".$templates->get("main")."\";");
```

Results from PHP and templates:

[image]
[image]

Now we can see that two users have points in the same category (points_first).
How can I do to get this effect? What to use?:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the results by the points and use GROUP_CONCAT to concatenate the usernames.

```sql
SELECT points_first, GROUP_CONCAT(username SEPARATOR ', ') AS users FROM users GROUP BY points_first ORDER BY points_first DESC;
```

I hope it is helpful!

Comment: Thank you very much!